# CDI SessionScoped Bean instance remains unchanged when login with different user

Tags: jsf, cdi, jboss-weld, j-security-check, session-scope

I've been looking for the workaround of this problem for rather plenty of time and no result, so I ask question here.

Simply speaking, I'm using a CDI SessionScoped Bean `User` in my project to manage user information and display them on jsf pages. Also container-managed `j_security_check` is used to resolve authentication issue.

Everything is fine if first logout with `session.invalidate()` and then login in the same browser tab with a different user. But when I tried to directly login (through `login.jsf`) with a new user without logout beforehand, I found the user information remaining unchanged.

I debugged and found the `User` bean, as well as the `HttpSession` instance, always remaining the same if login with different users in the same browser, as long as `session.invalidate()` not invoked. But oddly, the session id did modified, and I've both checked in Java code and Firebug.

```
org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@5d7b4092
StandardSession[c69a71d19f369d08b5dddbea2ef0]
attrName = org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator : attrValue=org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator@583c9dd8
attrName = org.jboss.weld.context.ConversationContext.conversations : attrValue = {}
attrName = org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContext#org.jboss.weld.bean-Discipline-ManagedBean-class com.netease.qa.discipline.profile.User : attrValue = Bean: Managed Bean [class com.netease.qa.discipline.profile.User] with qualifiers [@Any @Default @Named]; Instance: com.netease.qa.discipline.profile.User@c497c7c; CreationalContext: org.jboss.weld.context.CreationalContextImpl@739efd29
attrName = javax.faces.request.charset : attrValue = UTF-8

org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@5d7b4092
StandardSession[c6ab4b0c51ee0a649ef696faef75]
attrName = org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator : attrValue = org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator@583c9dd8
attrName = com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap : attrValue = {-4968076393130137442={-7694826198761889564=[Ljava.lang.Object;@43ff5d6c}}
attrName = org.jboss.weld.context.ConversationContext.conversations : attrValue = {}
attrName = org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContext#org.jboss.weld.bean-Discipline-ManagedBean-class com.netease.qa.discipline.profile.User : attrValue = Bean: Managed Bean [class com.netease.qa.discipline.profile.User] with qualifiers [@Any @Default @Named]; Instance: com.netease.qa.discipline.profile.User@c497c7c; CreationalContext: org.jboss.weld.context.CreationalContextImpl@739efd29
attrName = javax.faces.request.charset : attrValue = UTF-8
```

Above block contains two successive logins and their `Session` info. We can see that the instance(1st row) the same while session id(2nd row) different. Seems that session object is **reused** to contain different session id and CDI framework manages session bean life cycle in accordance with the session object only(?).

I'm wondering whether there could be only one server-side session object within the same browser unless invalidated?

Since I'm adopting `j_security_check` I fancy intercepting it and invalidating old session is not so easy. So is it possible to accomplish the goal without altering the CDI+JSF+j_security_check design that one can relogin with different account in the same or different tab within the same browser?

Really look forward for your response.

More info: 
Glassfish v3.1 is my appserver.

Comment: I established an `HttpSessionListener` and did find the `sessionCreated()` method invoked for each relogin. But the session instance(`org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade`) is always the same while `session.getId()` return different session id.